# Como crear o administrar multiples sesiones con express-session en node.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express-session

tengo un conflicto con el sistema de las sesiones al momento de usar express-session, tengo un sistema que maneja 3 tipos de usuario superadmin, admin, y usuarios genericos. La cuestión es que el sistema me crea una sesion y me la almacena correctamente pero cuando accedo al mismo tiempo al sistema con diferentes tipos de usuarios el sistema me usa la misma sesión y remplaza los valores, no me crea sesiones nuevas o diferentes, por lo cual si acceden 5 personas al sistema, los datos se sobre escriben con la ultima sesion y todos los datos para navegar en el sistema son de esa ultima sesion. Esto me genera un conflicto terrible para los multiusuarios y las multisesiones. Los registros de las sesiones se almacenan en bases de datos.

El siguiente codigo es como tengo el uso de express-session:

```
var sqlsession = new mysqlsession(database);

// middlewares
app.use(session({
  secret: 'SocratesMB',
  name: 'express-session',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: sqlsession,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 36000000,
    httpOnly: false,
  }
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride());
```

Eso es parte de mi codigo app.js donde inicializo las sesiones, no pongo todo el código porque no creo que sea necesario el resto de informacion.

Los siguientes son los datos que se guardan con la primer sesion en el sistema, he de decir que yo almaceno mas datos en la sesion para usarlo por medio de req.session.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para este caso el `ID de la sesion: _X_e4O5fjy5lJd1LhoXAC4gQsN9COIW5` ese es el inicio de sesion del superadmin pero cuando realizo el inicio de sesion de con otro usuario bajo el mismo hostname me sobre escribe la sesion resultando asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La sesion sigue siendo la misma por el id de esta `ID de la sesion: _X_e4O5fjy5lJd1LhoXAC4gQsN9COIW5` no me crea una nueva, muestro el id porque segun el repositorio con cada sesion es unico e independiente, en este caso no pasa, se sobre escriben.

Tambien el repositorio de express-session tiene una nota:

> Tenga en cuenta que si tiene varias aplicaciones que se ejecutan en el
> mismo nombre de host (esto es sólo el nombre, es decir, localhost o
> 127.0.0.1; los diferentes esquemas y puertos no nombran un nombre de host diferente), entonces necesita separar las cookies de sesión entre
> sí. El método más sencillo es simplemente establecer diferentes
> nombres por aplicación.

Pero no encuentro la manera de agregar eso cuando inicializo la session con el `app.use(session{})`, de igual manera me parece algo incorrecto separa las coookies por como lo recomienda el repositorio, debido a que el sistema en algún momento tendrá múltiples usuarios de cada tipo de rol, por lo cual pienso que las sesiones se sobre escribirían nuevamente.

Lo que busco es que con cada inicio de sesion en el sistema se cree una sesion nueva sin importar si solo son 2 usuarios o 500, los datos me los sobre escribe y no puedo tener multiusuario en mi aplicacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo logre solucionar evitando guardar en **`app.locals`** y creando un middleware que me convierta mi session de req en res local, ya que el usuario que hace el req, debe ser el mismo que responde.

En mi index agregué este middleware.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next();
});
```

Guardé mis variables en **`res.locals.session.variable`** y en mis vista llame las variables con **`session.variable`**, no es una solución optima, pero funciona, feliz día.

> **PD:** Me ayudo esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675738/how-to-expose-session-variables-to-express-views